# How to solve NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error?

Tags: php, codeigniter

The result print_f of notification is like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [notification_id] => 25
            [notification_message] => ada
            [notification_created_date] => 2016-06-30 15:25:32
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [notification_id] => 1
            [notification_message] => qwdqdd
            [notification_created_date] => 2016-06-22 15:27:01
        )

)
```

My view is like this :

```
<?php
    foreach ($notification as $key => $value) {
?>
        <li>
        <?php
            echo '<a href='.base_url().'notification/notif/'.$value['notification_id'].'>';
        ?>
                <span class="time">
                <?php 
                    echo time_elapsed($value['notification_created_date']); 
                ?>
                </span>
                <span class="details">
                    <span class="label label-sm label-icon label-info">
                        <i class="fa fa-bookmark"></i>
                    </span> <?php echo $value['notification_message']; ?>
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
<?php
    }
?>
```

My helper(time_elapsed helper) is like this : http://pastebin.com/AvsHYbxT

The construct in my controller is like this :

```
public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        time_elapsed($created_date=NULL);

        ...
    }
```

When executed, there is exist error like this :

```
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost/my-application/dashboard"
```

When I change `echo time_elapsed($value['notification_created_date']);` to `echo time_elapsed('2016-06-30 15:26:35');` , It's working. No error

So, If notification_created_date is static, no error

If `notification_created_date` is dynamic, I get an error.

Any solution to solve my problem?

Comment: Try replacing this:

`foreach ($notification as $key => $value) {`

to 

`foreach ($notification as $value) {`

Comment: @André Senra, It's not working. Look my question. I update my question

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I'm sorry, I had update it

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I'm still confused. How to check the logs?

Comment: there should be a place on your server panel if you're hosted, or in something like `/logs`. Or, use CI's error reporting method.

Comment: Does the function work with hard-coded datetime both in the past and future? `time_elapsed('2015-01-01)` and `time_elapsed('2017-01-01')`? Look in your php's `error_log` for the specifics of the error.

Comment: @BeetleJuice, I had try it. I change `echo time_elapsed('2015-06-30 15:26:35');` and I change `echo time_elapsed('2017-06-30 15:26:35');` too. It's not working

Comment: You said in your OP that `time_elapsed('2016-06-30 15:26:35')` works. Is that accurate?

Comment: @all, Solved. Thank you very much

Comment: Previous error, because there is no `function showdate()` in controller. Now I had add it and no error

Comment: Glad you worked it out. I strongly suggest you learn where PHP logs errors, so next time you see `Internal Server Error`, you can open the log and see right away which line triggered the error.

Comment: @BeetleJuice, I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38189488/how-to-remove-single-quotes-in-prepare-statement

Comment: @mosestoh please stop pinging people/me about other questions to look at; thanks. You've done this twice already.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I'm sorry